# Установка дефолтного значения поля сущности Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Есть сущность

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
public class Player {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Min(5)
@Max(25)
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "rank_id",)
private Rank rank;
```

И сущность

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rank")
public class Rank {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "permissions")
@ElementCollection
private Set<String> permissions = new HashSet<>();
```

У сущности Player есть поле с сущностью Rank. Каким образом можно установить дефолтное значение в поле

```
private Rank rank;
```

при инициализации сущности? И привязать его по полю name таблицы rank

Comment: ЧТо вы понимаете под инициализацией? Хибер сам вытаскивает поля и связывает

Comment: Инициализация в моем случае это либо создание новой сущности, либо поиск ее в бд.